# What is the ISecureDataFormat<TData> used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I do not really understand what this interface is used for, with the `Protect` and `Unprotect` methods,is only used to generate custom tokens?

```
namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security {
    public interface ISecureDataFormat<TData> {
        string Protect(TData data);
        TData Unprotect(string protectedText);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337308(v=vs.113).aspx - It appears to abstract away an encryption/decryption method

Comment: Represents the data to secrure... What data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is the OWIN required interface for the generation and of parsing security tokens such as Json Web Tokens(JWT). I have done some programming in this area and noticed in a recent sample that a programmer used the Thinktechture toolkit to generate a JWT that "Protect"s an OWIN implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Referred from https://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

There is no direct support for issuing JWT in ASP.NET Web API or ready made Owin middleware responsible for doing this, so in order to start issuing JWTs we need to implement this manually by implementing the interface “ISecureDataFormat” and implement the method “Protect”.

But, For .net core we have IdentityServerTools to issue jwt.